# How can I make areas of an imagemap act like checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, user-interface, checkbox, imagemap

I'm a crappy novice programmer and have been struggling to get this working for months!

I have an app which shows different places in a town.

The main page displays a map (.png of the town using paintshop) and its split into different areas.

The page also has some filter checkboxes to narrow down the results shown by area, which are displayed as pins on the .png map. So if I select the 'North' checkbox only the places in the North of the town are displayed.

I would like to get the areas of the map to act in the same way as the filter options. So that if the user clicks the North area on the map only the places in the North are shown and ALSO I would like the whole image of the town to be replaced with a differant image (a more zoomed in image of the Northern area of the town).

**Filter checkboxes** (Using the jQuery UI plugin)

```
<script>  
  $(function() {
    $(".areas").buttonset();
  }); 
</script>

<div class="filter_options_container">
  <%= form_tag '', :method => :get, :id => 'filter_form' do %>

    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
      <% Area.all.each do |a| %>
        <p class="area_check"><%= check_box_tag 'areas[]', a.id, false, :id => "area-#{a.id}" %>
        <label for="area-<%= a.id %>"><p1><%= a.name %></p1></label></p>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="filter_form_button">
      <p2><input type="submit" value="Filter"/></p2>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Index method**

```
def index
  if 
    @places = Place.with_area(params[:areas]).order("case plan when 'premium' then 1 else 0 end desc, average_rating DESC").all
  else
    @places = Place.all
  end
end
```

The results shown are rendered as partials:

```
<%= render :partial => 'place', :collection => @places %>
```

**Imagemap** (Using the jquery maphighlight plugin)

```
<script> 
 $(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
  });
</script>

<div class="map_container">

  <%= image_tag("maps/mainmap.png", :width => "450", :height => "450", :class => "map", :usemap => "#mainmap", :alt => "") %>

  <map name="mainmap">
    <area id="north" shape="poly" 
      coords="158,43,152,49,164,86,165,112,153,153,139,169,145,171,161,176,236,201,241,202,251,166,253,142,257,132,294,102,269,85,240,68,227,53,213,28,202,27" alt="North"
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >

    <area id="east" shape="poly" 
      coords="296,103,258,133,254,143,252,166,242,203,263,209,272,204,322,226,340,250,360,241,356,230,357,222,378,214,395,195,394,188" alt=""
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >
  </map>              
</div>
```

So I have working filter checkboxes and the imagemap correctly highlights on each area hover, how can I link the 2?

Thanks for any help its very much appreciated!

Comment: to me, the Ruby part of this seems irrelevent, the client side functionality is what's important. Could you set up a JSFiddle which contains everything that's output to the browser and some example image? I'd gladly take a look then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared a simple demo of what you can do:

http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/vUuJL/2/

The code is pretty straightforward!

I'm not sure if you really need radio buttons though.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I'm still fidling around to get it to fit with what I have already but it's helping alot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I can't help you with any of the Ruby that might be involved, you'll probably find the two jQuery methods [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) helpful.

You could add an onclick handler to each area of the map, which when clicked triggers the click event on it's corresponding checkbox.

`onclick="$('#corresponding_checkbox').trigger('click')"`

Or, without using the onclick attribute,

```
$('#east').on('click', function() {
    $('#east_checkbox').trigger('click');
});
```

You'd need to play around with the selectors, as I haven't gone through the Ruby to decipher them.

Hope that points you in the right direction.